# Using Session.get() in meteor helper methods causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework, angular-meteor

I am working on a angular-meteor (-ionic) application, where I need to display data from my collection based on a selected date from a calendar.
I use components for the different datatypes, and the calendar, and I link them together using a Session variable.

I encountered an infinite loop with the following code:

client/components/frontpage-cards/medicine/medicine-card.component.js

```
function MedicineCardController($scope, $reactive, $location) {
   $reactive(this).attach($scope);
   var vm = this;
   vm.subscribe('medicineData');

   vm.helpers({
      latestMedicineRegistration: () => {
         var selectedDate = Session.get('selectedDate');
         return Medicine.findOne(
            {
               // If I comment this no infinite-loop
               timestamp: {$lt: moment(selectedDate).toDate()}

            }, {
               sort: {
                  timestamp: -1,
                  createdAt: -1
               }
            });
      }
   }); 
}
```

client/components/frontpage-cards/medicine/bloodsample-card.component.js

```
vm.helpers({
      latestBloodsampleRegistration: () => {

         // If I comment this, also no infinite loop
         var selectedDate = Session.get('selectedDate');

         return Bloodsample.findOne(
            {
               //timestamp: {$lt: moment(selectedDate).toDate()}
            }, {
               sort: {
                  timestamp: -1,
                  createdAt: -1
               }
            });
      }
   });
```

For the calendar I am using the https://github.com/Russian60/flex-calendar component, which is the only one modifying the selected date:

client/components/calendar/calendar.component.js

```
function CalendarController($scope, $reactive) {
   $reactive(this).attach($scope);
   var vm = this;

   Session.set('selectedDate', new Date().valueOf());

   vm.options = {
      defaultDate: new Date(),
      minDate: "2015-01-01",
      maxDate: "2020-12-31",
      disabledDates: [],
      dayNamesLength: 1, 
      mondayIsFirstDay: true,
      eventClick: function (date) {
      },
      dateClick: function (date) {
         Session.set('selectedDate', date.date.valueOf());
      },
      changeMonth: function (month, year) {
         console.log('Month changed');
      }
   };
}
```

My frontpage is rendering both of these card components at the same time (and several more which are basically the same). A few things I have noticed:

- this only happens when there is no matching entry found in the collections, e.g. the helper returns undefined
- if only one of the helpers contains the Session.get(), it is working as expected
- the loop happens when I select a new date in the calendar, which returns no valid data, and then select ANOTHER date which also contains no valid data (so the loop doesn't happen on the first selection, but 2nd, sometimes only on 3rd)
- I get the repeating console message of overriding all my helpers that use the Session.get() - this is how I noticed an infite loop, but this stops as soon as I manage to select a date which returns existing data

Comment: Can you console timestamp in your code? `timestamp: {$lt: moment(selectedDate).toDate()}`

Comment: Yes, I can also verify the data is correct in the database. As it seems, if I only had one type of data with one active helper it works as expected

Comment: Can you try instead dynamic time by fixed time to test again?